# Make my tabs be on the left with my content next to it on the right

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am trying to have my tabs on left left instead of on top with the content to the right next to it.

How can I do this with what I already have.

This is what I have:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
 
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}

/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        /* float:left; */
        list-style:none;
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        background:#fff;
        width: auto;
    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
    </ul>
 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cy33jjo1/

To get something like this: http://codepen.io/joshadamous/full/wJKzv/

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are chain of reasons why you can't get it work, and that is as belows:

**1)** Do not apply `display:inline-block;` and `float:left;` to containers in your case `.tabs`

**2)** Instead apply `display:inline-block;` and `float:left;` to inside elements. In your case to `.tab-links` and `.tab-contents`.

**3)** Also `ul` **takes some margin and padding by default** even if you do not specify. So making them to `0px's`.

**4)** Now you want your `.tab-content` to right of `.tab-links` such that it **covers rest of the `width`**.

So for that you must know the `width` of `.tab-links`(which we are unaware here), as result you can use that `width` for `.tab-content` like `width:calc(100% - {width_Of_TabLinks} px);`.

**5)** We will be **using JQuery to know width of `.tab-links`** and use that further.

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/cy33jjo1/2/)</kbd>**

**HTML** : No-Change

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}

/*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    /*display:inline-block; REMOVED*/
    /*float: left; REMOVED*/
}

/*----- Tab Links -----*/
.tab-links /* ADDED */
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}

/* Clearfix */ 
.tab-links:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';
}

.tab-links li {
    /*margin:0px 5px; REMOVED */
    list-style:none;
}

.tab-links a {
    padding:9px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#7FB5DA;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
    background:#a7cce5;
    text-decoration:none;
}

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#4c4c4c;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
.tab-content {
    padding:15px;
    background:#fff;
    width: auto;        
    /*Added*/
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;        
}

.tab {
    display:none;
}

.tab.active {
    display:block;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
 //Added this two lines to your JQuery

 var wTabLinks = $(".tab-links").outerWidth();
 $(".tab-content").css("width", "calc(100% - " + wTabLinks + "px - 30px)");
```

> **Note:** You can see `-30px` in above JQuery code, that is because of `padding:9px 15px;` in your `.tab-content {....}`. Here you have gave `15px` to left and right padding to Tab Content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/cy33jjo1/1/

Just change this in your css

```
.tab-content {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: 127px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  width: 60%;
}
```